# Prove (¬(∀(¬()))) ⊢ (∃ ()) by Natural Deduction

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

I want to prove (¬(∀(¬()))) ⊢ (∃()) using only the basic rules of the Natural Deduction system for propositional logic and predicate logic.

I am not sure how to get rid of the negation before the universal quantifier.

How should I prove this?

Answer (score 4):

If in doubt, try reductio ....

So after the initial premiss, assume $\neg\exists xPx$

Now what?

You'll have to make another assumption to get anywhere ....

So suppose $Pa$ (the obvious thing ...why??)

Then you can infer $\exists xPx$, contradiction!

So you can infer $\neg Pa$

And that gives you $\forall x\neg Px$

And now the end is in sight, because this contradicts the initial premiss ...

Join up the dots, and finish the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Natural deduction rules are all about introduction and eliminations of connectives and quantifiers.   Hence the rules' names.   Writing a natural deduction proof basically consists of deciding what needs to be introduced or eliminated *and when*.   The rules themselves tell you how.

> I am not sure how to get rid of the negation before the universal quantifier.

Okay, obviously, eliminating the negation will be done using the rule of *negation elimination*.   That was easy!

Well, the hard bit of this is arranging to have what the rule requires.   Although it is not *that* hard.

It requires two contradicting statements and we have only one premise in the base context.   An assumption must be raised!   So what do we assume to derive a contradiction of the premise?   Also what do we do with that contradiction?

Well, if the premise actually does entails the conclusion, assuming the contrary should derive a contradiction.   So let us assume that: $\neg\exists x~P(x)$ , and aim to derive this: $\forall x~\lnot P(x)$.   This also tells use what we're doing with that contradiction.   We will be using a proof by *reduction to absurdity* — discharging the assumption by introducing a negation, and then eliminating the double negation that results to derive the desired conclusion.

Okay, now, to get that contradiction you need to introduce a universal quantifier.   Continue thinking in this manner and the proof almost writes itself.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{\neg\forall x~\neg P(x)\qquad~~~\textsf{Premise}}{\fitch{\neg\exists x~P(x)\qquad\textsf{Assumption}}{~\vdots\\\forall x~\neg P(x)\qquad\textsf{Universal Introduction}\\\bot\qquad\qquad\quad~\textsf{Negation Elimination}}\\\neg\neg\exists x~P(x)\qquad\quad\textsf{Negation Introduction}\\\exists x~P(x)\qquad\qquad\textsf{Double Negation Elimination}}$$

Comment: That is a good proof outline.